# How to authenticate the user with Designer workflow 2013 and REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I've to call the web service for POST operation.

I'd set **"Workflows can use app permissions"** but still not getting result.
And getting the following error-

> {"error":{"code":"-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access
>   denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access
>   this resource."}}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your REST call are you specifying the `X-RequestDigest` parameter in its headers? If not, you need to. Every REST call needs to be authenticated.

You can find an excellent step-by-step guide on how to do this here:

http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/10/09/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-working-with-web-services/

In case the link goes dead I copy the text below:

> When working with the SharePoint REST services you need to
>   authenticate the requests.
>
> There is a service available to take care of this.  This step will
>   build a Dictionary object for the request headers and then call the
>   service to get the security token.  First we’ll create a new
>   Dictionary action, output it to a variable called contextHeaders, and
>   create entries for Accept, Content-Type, and Content-Length headers. 
>   For Accept and Content-Type, we want to use “application/json;
>   odata=verbose.”  SharePoint 2013 REST calls require the second
>   parameter, “odata=verbose,” because while the OData specification
>   supports other options, SharePoint’s services do not.
>
> Next, we’ll create a “Call HTTP Web Service” action to get the token.
>
> Also, you must use the POST method to get this token.  While you would
>   expect to use a GET call, the reason for POST is to improve security
>   against “shady” requests.  Next, we’ll need to assign a variable to
>   the ResponseContent of the action.  This is a Dictionary object we’ll
>   call contextResponse.  Finally, we need to set the RequestHeaders
>   property of the action to our contextHeaders dictionary.
>
> Right-click on the action and select “Properties…” to access the
>   action’s properties window.